# Importing data from file into an int array that's called from a different class

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a program that deals with inheritance. Below is one of the class that is extended from my super class bus.

```
    public BusTrip(){
      super();
      int totalPassenger = 0;
      fare = new int [3];
      numOfPassenger = new int [3];
      String destination = "";
   }
```

I am having trouble in my driver class to import data into my ArrayList. I understand that it's reading everything in the data file position 4 all the way to the end of to the string. I have tried a while loop as well but that does not seem to go past the first set of data. Is tokenizer the only method? Is there a way for me to prevent the for loop from reading pass a certain point?

Data File

cr, greyhound, 2015, 30, 22, 44, 14, 10, 5, 15, New York

```
public static void readAllBus(ArrayList<Bus> busInformation){
      File infile = null;
      Scanner scan = null;
      int[] fare = new int [3];
      int[] numOfPassenger = new int [3];

      try{
         infile = new File("busData.csv");
         scan = new Scanner(infile);
      }//end try
      catch(FileNotFoundException e){
         System.out.println("Error! File not found!");
         System.exit(0);
      }//end catch

      while(scan.hasNext()){
         String [] str = scan.nextLine().split(",");

         if(str[0].equals("cr")){
            for(int i = 0; i < fare.length; i++)
              for(int j = 4; j < str.length; j++)
                fare[i] = Integer.parseInt(str[j]);
           //error For input string: "Bahamas"
            for(int i = 0; i < numOfPassenger.length; i++)
              for(int j = 7; j < str.length; j++)
                numOfPassenger[i] = Integer.parseInt(str[j]);
            //error For input string: "Bahamas"
            busInformation.add(new BusTrip(str[1],
                                Integer.parseInt(str[2]),
                                Integer.parseInt(str[3]),
                                fare,
                                numOfPassenger,
                                str[10]));

         }//end if
      }//end while
   }//end readAllBus
```

Comment: what do you mean by `//error For input string: "Bahamas"`

Comment: Just change the loops' conditions. `j < str.length` means that the loop will have `str.length - j` number of iterations. To iterate a specific number of times, you can use a condition like this `j < j+3` (loop only 3 times).

Comment: Scary Wombat that's is an error it throws out at me because it does the array I'm attempting to store with is an int. This is due to the setup of the loops.                                                                                                                @Titus Could you write a more detailed answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a bug in the for loop. You are executing the inner loop multiple times when you just wanted to read the value only once. You could rewrite your logic as follows -

> ```
> public static void readAllBus(ArrayList<Bus> busInformation){
>   File infile = null;
>   Scanner scan = null;
>   int[] fare = new int [3];
>   int[] numOfPassenger = new int [3];
>
>   try{
>      infile = new File("busData.csv");
>      scan = new Scanner(infile);
>   }//end try
>   catch(FileNotFoundException e){
>      System.out.println("Error! File not found!");
>      System.exit(0);
>   }//end catch
>
>   while(scan.hasNext()){
>      String [] str = scan.nextLine().split(",");
>
>      if(str[0].equals("cr")){
>
>      if(str.length>7){
>           for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
>           fare[i] = Integer.parseInt(str[i+4]);
>           }
>       }
>
>       if(str.length>10){
>         for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
>           numOfPassenger[i] = Integer.parseInt(str[i+7]);
>           }
>        }
>
>       busInformation.add(new BusTrip(str[1],
>                            Integer.parseInt(str[2]),
>                            Integer.parseInt(str[3]),
>                            fare,
>                            numOfPassenger,
>                            str[10]));
>
>     }//end if
>   }//end while    
>  }//end readAllBus
> ```

Comment: I see. I thought it was necessary to for loop it twice since I figure there's two arrays. Though, isn't my inner only consider locally scale since it was within my first loop?